# WMS not viewing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to import WMS from geoserver link to QGIS 2.8.4 & the latest 2.12.1: 
http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/asig/wms&

QGIS get the request and show the layers of the workspace, and also the get info.
My problem is that the layer is not visible in the view.

It works fine with version 2.2:

[image]

Comment: have you checked the do not use URL from capabilities box? or does that URL appear in the getCapabilities file?

Comment: yes i have tried , and its the same problem.

Comment: what happens when you pan around the map? Sometimes that helps my WMS/OpenLayers problems in QGIS.

Comment: No its doesn't show anything , i have tried and in udig and it works perfect

Comment: It appears it might be a bug.  I agree I can load the service and QGIS seems to be firing off the correct requests in the background like (http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/asig/ows&&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=345119.95276619656942785,4471884.15714104659855366,505943.44039006857201457,4676393.70502723939716816&CRS=EPSG:32634&WIDTH=573&HEIGHT=729&LAYERS=cz_division&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE) but I, like you, have a blank map. on Linux Mint with QGIS 2.12-3

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows 10 with GIS 2.12.3

Comment: Only other thought is that it could be an issue with scale layering

Comment: maybe its a bug of qgis  regarding  the proxy part.

Comment: Did you try to change your CRS from 4326 to 32634 ?

Comment: @Artec It didn't work for me using either EPSG:4326 or EPSG:32634 in QGIS 2.12.3 on windows 10 or on Linux, does it work for you?  I tried in an OpenLayers client using  EPSG:4326 and it works, so something very odd is going on.  If I use Fiddler to look at the request that QGIS sends, then display that request in a browser I get the map! So for some reason QGIS won't display the map.  There is scale layering on the service, so that might be the root cause.

Comment: @nmtoken Some time ago I had a problem with other geoportal WMS and was solved by changing the CRS. But now it doesn't work for me to. I used WMS adress from http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/en/Tutorial.aspx which is different that one from this question. I'm not sure that is a problem with QGIS, because Geomedia can't open this WMS to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell this appears to be an error with QGIS stripping the host name off the url; so I get errors in the console like:

`Map request failed [error:Protocol "" is unknown url:/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/asig/ows&&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=345119.95276619656942785,4499106.68403259478509426,503972.04766661184839904,4603200.33713638130575418&CRS=EPSG:32634&WIDTH=640&HEIGHT=419&LAYERS=cz_division&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1]`

I checked the value of the URL stored in the registry something like:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\QGIS\QGIS2\Qgis\connections-wms\your-service-name`

And that seems correct

I created a GDAL WMS mini driver (see http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html for all the options) as below

```
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="WMS">
        <ServerUrl>http://geoportal.asig.gov.al/Services/host/host.ashx?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/asig/wms</ServerUrl>
        <ImageFormat>image/png</ImageFormat>
        <Layers>cz_division</Layers>
        <BBoxOrder>xyXY</BBoxOrder>
        <SRS>EPSG:32634</SRS>
        <CRS>EPSG:32634</CRS>
        <Transparent>TRUE</Transparent>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>359060.34375</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>4719675.5</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>505375.90625</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>4387020.0</LowerRightY>
        <SizeX>1024</SizeX>
        <SizeY>1024</SizeY>
    </DataWindow>
    <UserAgent>GDAL WMS driver (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html)</UserAgent>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Then I add this through the add raster layer tool, and I get the map.

So you can use one or more mini drivers to get the maps showing in QGIS, but really you should probably report the issue to QGIS to get a proper fix:

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

If you look at the layer properties > layer source of a WMS layer that works, for example :

`contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=2&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=BMNG&styles=&url=http://mapsref.brgm.fr/wxs/1GG
/monde1GG?`

You can see that it chops the request up into several pieces including an url parameter.  I think the QGIS issue with the ASIG service is that the ASIG service itself defines an URL parameter.

Comment: I saved this as .xml file and used gdal_translate -of JPEG in.xml out.jpg but with error. How did you use this driver ?

Comment: Save the file as an XML file,  then in QGIS select 'Add Raster Layer' (for me the second icon down on the left hand side, or through  ```Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer```)  and browse to the XML file.  That's it

Comment: I tried this to, but I've got an error "Raster layer: C:\...\Test.xml is not a supported raster data source"

Comment: Is the file valid, does it have the the closing </GDAL_WMS> tag?  I see that the example file I pasted wasn't showing that tag (now corrected), so if you just did a copy/save on that original example there would have been some error.

Comment: I did as you wrote but still I have the same error: "Raster layer: C:\Users\...\Desktop\Test\Test.xml is not a supported raster data source". Only after changing file encoding to ANSI driver works fine. Thanks.